# CSS3 2D Transforms not working on IE9 if set by jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, 2d, transform, internet-explorer-9

As per title, I'm translating and rotating an object with CSS3's transform and it works flawlessly in every browser except IE9.

It works in IE9 **but only if it's written directly into the .css file**. It fails if set by jQuery (v. 1.5.1) with:

```
$('#example').css('-ms-transform', 'translate(200%) rotate(45deg) translate(-200%)');
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is causing the problem. However, have you tried with cssText:

> $('#example').css('cssText','-ms-transform: translate(200%) rotate(45deg) translate(-200%)');

Sometimes this would seem to work.

EDIT: I believe the problem is related to this jQuery issue:

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8346

Comment: Hey it works! Thanks! :) So the problem was jQuery itself? Or it's an ie bug with setting the css via JavaScript?